# How to define same-named elements in DTD having different parent elements?

Tags: xml, dtd

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<data>
  <authors>
    <author>
      <name>
        <first_name>Stephen</first_name>
        <last_name>Baxter</last_name>
      </name>
    </author>
    <author>
      <name>
        <first_name>Joe</first_name>
        <last_name>Haldeman</last_name>
      </name>
    <author>
  </authors>
  <books>
    <book>
      <name>The Time Ships</name>
    </book>
    <book>
      <name>The Forever War</name>
    <book>
  </books>
</data>
```

In my DTD, how would I account for the fact that the "name" element is used for both authors and books and can have different child elements--like this?

```
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA|first_name,last_name)>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your `name` element is mixed content (both child elements or #PCDATA), you're going to have to change your element declaration to this:

```
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA|first_name|last_name)*>
```

This means that you are going to have to use something other than DTD to enforce that `name` contains `#PCDATA` *or* one `first_name` followed by one `last_name`.